# React Redux: Infinite Loop when dispatch

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I observed that this problem is common, but I didn't find a solution for my case.

I'm trying to redirect the user to another navigator in react native, using react and redux with redux-thunk. If I display just Home screen it works fine, but when I'm redirecting from SignIn screen to Home, it goes into an infinite loop, I found the problem is in the dispatch function.

```
import {
  FETCHING_CATEGORIES_REQUEST,
  FETCHING_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS,
  FETCHING_CATEGORIES_FAILURE,
} from "../types"

import { Categories } from "../../services/firebase"

export const fetchingCategoriesRequest = () => ({
  type: FETCHING_CATEGORIES_REQUEST,
})

export const fetchingCategoriesSuccess = data => ({
  type: FETCHING_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS,
  payload: data,
})

export const fetchingCategoriesFailure = error => ({
  type: FETCHING_CATEGORIES_FAILURE,
  payload: error,
})

export const fetchCategories = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchingCategoriesRequest())
    Categories.get()
      .then(data => dispatch(fetchingCategoriesSuccess(data)))
      .catch(error => dispatch(fetchingCategoriesFailure(error)))
  }
}
```

Routing

```
import { createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation"

import PrivateNavigator from "./private"
import PublicNavigator from "./public"

const Navigator = (signedIn = false) => {
  return createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      Private: {
        screen: PrivateNavigator,
      },
      Public: {
        screen: PublicNavigator,
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: signedIn ? "Private" : "Public",
    },
  )
}

export default Navigator
```

Redirecting

```
import React from "react"
import { Spinner } from "native-base"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import Navigator from "../navigation"

class AppContainer extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    const { isLogged, loading } = this.props.auth

    const Layout = Navigator(isLogged)
    return loading ? <Spinner /> : <Layout />
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    ...state,
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {},
)(AppContainer)
```

Comment: where is the `redirect` ?

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: hum don't see why threre is an infinite loop but your `mapStateToProps` function could be better ->  `const mapStateToProps = state => state.auth`. currently with your code, the render method will be executed for each modification in the store (even if `auth` has not been changed)

Comment: Guess, it solved my problem, thank you :D

Comment: are you sure because I made a mistake, it's `const mapStateToProps = state => ({auth: state.auth})` ranther than `const mapStateToProps = state => state.auth`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be careful with `mapStateToProps`, you should only select the part of the store you're interested in, otherwise performance problems could occur

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({auth: state.auth});
```

A little explanation how react-redux `connect` works,

1. each time there is a modification in the store (from the reducers), the `mapStateToProps` functions of all the connected components are executed
2. if the one prop in the returned object is different from the previous one (the operator `===` is used) then the component is re-rendered otherwise it does nothing.

In your example, as you select all the props of the store, your component will be re-rendered for each modification in the store

Comment: This answers the most of it, but if you also update answer for hooks it will be great, 

In second go it cleared to me, with respect to react-hooks

Comment: just to answer above, `useSelector` most likely wrap the `mapStateToProps` so that you don't have to write a higher order component. I never used it, but i assume this is how it works :)