# React dispatch going in the infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, redux-saga

While making a post request my request is going in a loop. Not sure why it's happening. Its happening at the handleSubmit of the form. I referred few question from stackoverflow but it did not helped me. Still looking for a solution. Dammm its Ruined my SUNDAY.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { FORGOT_PASSWORD } from "../../redux/types";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import AuthLayout from "../../layouts/Auth";

export default function ForgotPassword() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    console.log(email,'---get email')
    e.preventDefault();
    const payload = { email };
    //loginUser(payload)
    console.log(payload,'=====')
    dispatch({ type: FORGOT_PASSWORD, payload });
  };

  return (
    <AuthLayout>
      <div className="container mx-auto px-4 h-full">
        <div className="flex content-center items-center justify-center h-full">
          <div className="w-full lg:w-4/12 px-4">
            <div className="relative flex flex-col min-w-0 break-words w-full mb-6 shadow-lg rounded-lg bg-blueGray-200 border-0">
              <div className="rounded-t mb-0 px-6 py-6">
                <div className="text-blueGray-400 text-center mb-3 font-bold">
                  <center>Reset your password </center>
                </div>
                <hr className="mt-6 border-b-1 border-blueGray-300" />
              </div>
              <div className="flex-auto px-4 lg:px-10 py-10 pt-0">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <div className="relative w-full mb-3">
                    <label
                      className="block uppercase text-blueGray-600 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                      htmlFor="grid-password"
                    >
                      Email
                    </label>
                    <input
                      value={email}
                      onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                      type="email"
                      required
                      className="border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-blueGray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                      placeholder="Email"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="text-center mt-6">
                    <button
                      className="bg-blueGray-800 text-white active:bg-blueGray-600 text-sm font-bold uppercase px-6 py-3 rounded shadow hover:shadow-lg outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                      type="submit"
                    >
                      {/* {loading ? "Sending email..." : "Reset Password"} */} Reset Password
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-wrap mt-6 relative">
              <div className="w-1/2">
                <Link to="/auth/forgot-password" className="text-blueGray-200">
                  Login?
                </Link>
              </div>
              <div className="w-1/2 text-right">
                <Link to="/auth/register" className="text-blueGray-200">
                  Create new account
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </AuthLayout>
  );
}
```

This is my Redux looks like

```
import { LOGIN, REGISTER, LOGOUT, FORGOT_PASSWORD } from "../types";

const initialState = {};

const auth = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case LOGIN:
      return { ...state, ...payload };
    case REGISTER:
      return { ...state, ...payload };
    case LOGOUT:
      return { ...state, ...payload };
    case FORGOT_PASSWORD:
      return { ...state, ...payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default auth;
```

And this is how my SAGA looks like

```
export function* forgotPassword({ payload }) {
  yield put({ type: FORGOT_PASSWORD, payload: { loading: true } });
  try {
    const { status } = yield authService.forgotPassword(payload);
    if (status === 204) {
      const key = 'updatable';
      // notification.success({ message: "Logged in successfully" });
      message.loading({ content: 'Loading...', key });
      message.success({ content: 'Reset password link sent to your email!', key, duration: 4 });
      //window.location.replace("/dashboard");
    } else yield put({ type: FORGOT_PASSWORD, payload: { loading: false } });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: FORGOT_PASSWORD, payload: { loading: false } });
  }
}
```

The issue I when I submit that form it just goes in loop. INFINITE LOOP

EDIT-

After debugging I see it keep looping at SAGA and SERVICE CALL [JUST IN CASE THE API I AM CALLING HAS RESPONSE SUCCESS CODE 204]

```
// THIS IS SERVICE CALL
const userInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3005/v1/',
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  timeout: 10000,
  responseType: "json",
  validateStatus: (status) => status < 400,
});


// BELOW IS THE API call I am making
    async function forgotPassword(payload) {
      return userInstance
        .post("/auth/forgot-password", payload)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response) {
            return response;
          }
          return false;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
```

And this is my SAGA FUCNTION

```
  export function* forgotPassword({ payload }) {
      console.log('======AT SAGA', payload);
      yield put({ type: FORGOT_PASSWORD, payload: payload });
      try {
               // here below line the SERVICE function for API call is called
        const { status } = yield forgotPassword(payload);
        if (status === 204) {
          const key = 'updatable';
          // notification.success({ message: "Logged in successfully" });
          message.loading({ content: 'Loading...', key });
          message.success({ content: 'Reset password link sent to your email!', key, duration: 4 });
          //window.location.replace("/dashboard");
        } else yield put({ type: FORGOT_PASSWORD, payload: { loading: false } });
      } catch (error) {
        yield put({ type: FORGOT_PASSWORD, payload: { loading: false } });
      }
    }
//EXPORT ALL TO ROOT
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery(LOGIN, login),
    takeEvery(REGISTER, register),
    takeEvery(LOGOUT, logoutUser),
  ]);

  yield all([takeEvery(FORGOT_PASSWORD, forgotPassword)]);
}
```

SO AFTER DEBUGGING IT JUST KEEP LOOPING INFINITE - FROM SAGA FUNCTION TO THE SERVICE CALL FUNCTION WHERE ITs been called at SAGA.

Comment: Hmm, how do you consume `forgotPassword` function? Is it something like `takeLatest("FORGOT_PASSWORD", forgotPassword)`?

Comment: If yes then it's an issue. Just use some different action type for the saga, do not reuse action type for reducer. e.g. `takeLatest("FORGOT_PASSWORD_SAGA", forgotPassword)`, and in the component `handleSubmit = () => { /* some code... */  dispatch({ type: "FORGOT_PASSWORD_SAGA", payload })}`

Comment: what is `put` here, is that similar to dispatch ?

Comment: try this post, i run into quite a bit problem with redux in the past, and this issues summarized it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171004/react-redux-infinite-loop-when-dispatch

Comment: @windmaomao how to deal with functional components?

Comment: @hackape since those are just CONSTANTS so I think does not matter. I tried changing but yet the same issue. Also I am not consuming the ```export function* forgotPassword({ payload }) ``` function I use it via CONSTANT TYPE in the component in ```handleSubmit``` function.

Comment: @Monty your code is much fancy that that post's answer. The point here is that if you ever use `useSelector` somewhere, or any `redux` state map, you need to make sure it's very selective. Otherwise one part of your app could depend on any state change in redux state. And infinate loop is normally created from there. Your shared code seems fine, but your other part of code might have this issue.

Comment: Try put a debug message right after Component defination. ex. `export default function ForgotPassword() { console.log('Forgot Password') }`. This will tell u how many times this component re-renders, Of course the real problem might not happen in this component. When using `redux`, you have to mindfully monitor this behavior.

Comment: @windmaomao I have edited question after debuggning

Comment: @hackape I have updated question after debug

Answer (score 0):

I’m pretty sure it’s because you use the action type `"FORGOT_PASSWORD"` for triggering both state update in reducer and the saga function.

You said you’ve tried my solution. But I doubt you’re still missing some points. So I’mma post the solution again in full details.

My reasoning:

1. `put` in saga function is effectively `dispatch` in redux’s term.
2. You `dispatch({ type: "FORGOT_PASSWORD" })` from `handleSubmit` to trigger initial run of saga, the action first arrives at the redux store
3. The saga middleware pickup the action because `takeEvery("FORGOT_PASSWORD", forgotPassword)`, it’s now routed to `forgotPassword` saga function
4. `forgotPassword` run some side-effects, and eventually you wanna tell the redux reducer to update the state. So you `put({ type: "FORGOT_PASSWORD" })` wishing it would reach the reducer.
5. Surprisingly, this action is once again pickup by the saga middleware in step 3, routed back to `forgotPassword`, now you’re in a infinite loop.

Notice throughout the above explanation I always use string literals to present action types? `"FORGOT_PASSWORD"` with double quotes.

You said in the comment

> those are just CONSTANTS so I think does not matter

Obviously you missed the crucial point. Off course I don’t mean to change the constants variable name, I mean change the action types’ **string literal**.